# How do I view synonyms indexed in a document?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have added a synonyms token filter to my index and I think it is working as planned, but I want a way to confirm the exact values that are being stored for each document (some queries aren't using the synonym values as I expect, and I need to verify if the right values were stored at the time of indexing).

Is there a standard way to figure this out?

**Example:**

1. At some point I configured a synonym for NICE and PLEASANT.
2. At some point I indexed a document that has the word NICE in it.

**Givens**

- _termvectors shows my document has the term NICE in it.
- _analyze for my analyzer shows NICE and PLEASANT are synonyms.

**Question:**

How can I tell if the indexed document is using PLEASANT as a term/synonym?

---

**Update**

Adapting the answer from user3775217 (I had to update the syntax to work for ElasticSearch 5.2):

```
{
  "query":{
    "term": { "{someFieldToFilterOn}": "{SomeFieldValue}"}
  },
  "script_fields":{
    "terms":{
      "script":{
        "lang":"groovy",
        "inline":"doc[field].values",
        "params":{
          "field":"{TheFieldIwantIndexedTermsFrom}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have prepared this query couple of years back to find the indexed values for the document. You can use this query to learn about the values indexed in the field for each document.

You will need doc_id for each document and the document field you want to check on.

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/test-idx/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "_id": "1770"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "terms": {
      "script": "doc[field].values",
      "params": {
        "field": "input"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Won't looking in the doc field values just give me back field values from the original document? How would I use that to figure out what synonym terms were indexed for a given document?

Comment: field values will give you all the terms indexed for for your fields, fields values is different from _source values. Just like we need to push not_analyzed for using in term aggregation for words with spaces.